# Dart: HttpException: Failed to parse header value

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, dart

I get an

> HttpException: Failed to parse header value

when calling the http.Client.get(Uri) method using the [M2 release](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/m2-whats-new/) dart [http](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http) and [oauth2](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/oauth2) libraries.  I'm trying to use the API to perform a [File: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get).  I successfully redirected my authorization request to a simple console-based http server to acquire the token.  The following code then results in the exception:

```dart
oauth.Credentials credentials = new oauth.Credentials(code);
http.Client client = new oauth.Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, credentials);
Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/$fileID");
Future<http.Response> result = client.get(uri);
```

The following is the full stack trace:

```
HttpException: Failed to parse header value
Unhandled exception:
FutureUnhandledException: exception while executing Future
HttpException: Failed to parse header value
original stack trace:
  null
#0      _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:844:11)
#1      _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:848:5)
#2      _FutureImpl._setException (bootstrap:873:14)
#3      _CompleterImpl.completeException (bootstrap:952:30)
#4      _FutureImpl._forwardException.<anonymous closure> (bootstrap:936:34)
#5      _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:832:22)
#6      _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:848:5)
#7      _FutureImpl._setException (bootstrap:873:14)
#8      _CompleterImpl.completeException (bootstrap:952:30)
#9      _FutureImpl._forwardException.<anonymous closure> (bootstrap:936:34)
#10     _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:832:22)
#11     _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:848:5)
#12     _FutureImpl._setException (bootstrap:873:14)
#13     _CompleterImpl.completeException (bootstrap:952:30)
#14     _FutureImpl._forwardException.<anonymous closure> (bootstrap:936:34)
#15     _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:832:22)
#16     _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:848:5)
#17     _FutureImpl._setException (bootstrap:873:14)
#18     _CompleterImpl.completeException (bootstrap:952:30)
#19     _FutureImpl._forwardException.<anonymous closure> (bootstrap:936:34)
#20     _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:832:22)
#21     _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:848:5)
#22     _FutureImpl._setException (bootstrap:873:14)
#23     _CompleterImpl.completeException (bootstrap:952:30)
#24     IOClient.send.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:http/src/io_client.dart:38:36)
#25     _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:840:19)
#26     _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:848:5)
#27     _FutureImpl._setValue (bootstrap:862:14)
#28     _CompleterImpl.complete (bootstrap:949:26)
#29     async.<anonymous closure> (package:http/src/utils.dart:173:41)
#30     _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (dart:io:7035:28)
#31     _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (dart:io:7043:7)
#32     _Timer._createTimerHandler.<anonymous closure> (dart:io:7051:23)
#33     _ReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch:37:92)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the [Google Drive SDK API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) you can use [Google APIs Client Library for Dart](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dart-client/) which enables access to Google APIs from Dart applications.

https://github.com/Scarygami/dart-google-oauth2-library was built off of this and it works as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized SSL perhaps?

```
SecureSocket.initialize();
```

See http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/SecureSocket.html for more information.

Comment: Thank you.  Good point.  I did initialize using this command.